# Scala: How to determine the exception type of a Failure

Tags: scala, exception, error-handling

Look at this code snippet:

```
userService.insert(user) match {
  case Success(f) => Logger.debug("User created successfully")
  case Failure(e) => {
     // how do I determine the type of `e`?
  }
}
```

How do I determine the type of the exception contained by `Failure`? I need to take different actions depending on the exception type.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
case Success(f) => 
case Failure(e: ExceptionType1) =>
case Failure(e: ExceptionType2) => 
case Failure(e) => // other
```

or

```
case Success(f) =>
case Failure(e) => e match {
   case e1: ExceptionType1 =>
   case e2: ExceptioNType2 =>
   case _ => 
}
```

Comment: @Didier, which seems more idiomatic to you? The latter seems clearer to me since the inner match relates to `Exceptions` only.

Comment: Not sure if one of them is more standard. I believe I would use the first one, except if there is a common behavior in case of failure:  you may put other instructions than the e match in the Failure case. Both look fine to me, use whichever one suits you.

Comment: I think the first is much clearer as it avoids nesting; even in the presence of shared behaviour I'd be more inclined to use `case Failure(e: Ex1) | Failure(e: Ex2) => …`.

Comment: There might be some behavior common to both exception and some  specific to each?

Answer (score 0):

or

```scala
case Success(f) =>
case Failure(e @ _: ExceptionType1) =>
case Failure(e @ _: ExceptionType2 | ExceptionType3) =>
case Failure(e) =>
```